# Does the placement of a back-link really affect is value?

Tags: backlinks

This is a question that's been going through my mind a lot recently, and nobody online has given me a solid answer. Does the placement of your **do-follow** back-link actually affect how well it preforms?

For example, one person has an entire write up dedicated towards your back-link and it's thrown somewhere in the middle, but another blog just throws your back-link in the footer of their website for the same duration of time, and finally someone just pastes your link on a forum / comment portion of some sort in a paid back-link service.

Will these back-links work the same way if they're all do-follow back-links or will the one with the write up actually out preform the latter two?

Comment: Yes. Links within content will always perform better depending upon content quality and link quality. Lousy content and a poor link will not perform at all well.

Comment: @closetnoc So if I'm back linking from my own sites, how would you recommend doing it in a way that will benefit every post on my website, if including it in the footer is bad practice?

Comment: Links in footers, headers, and sidebars can be considered spammy if not done appropriately. Be natural and do what a reasonable webmaster would do. Especially between sites. Do not think linking between your sites will increase your rank. Links within content is best and the link text should semantically describe the target page and should be relevant the content the link is in. Don't try and game the system. That does not work.

Comment: Google can associate links such as branding and niche. Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, are associated for example.

Answer (score 1):

> Links in footers, headers, and sidebars can be considered spammy if not done appropriately

True 100%

But think twice before NOT post a link. Beside being on top of organic result, your business need customers and usually mouth to mouth is a good source of customers. And a link "anywhere" can bring you a customer not via search result but directly via the "backlink". For example: you have a stationary/bookshop. If you place many backlink in many small blog or school news blog of your area maybe can "eventually" be consider spammy but this does not exclude that many people/students could click that link and see what you can offer to them... so when you build your back link don't think only about SERP, think about if it will be useful for who will see these links to click it and automatically you will find yourself building a NON spammy backlinks network.